# Pass selected view to main player Angular/Youtube

Tags: angular, youtube, components

So today I am trying to complete an angular project I have been sitting on a while. Its a mock YouTube app using youtubes api to fetch an display resouces. I cant seem to get past sending my vids from the video list to the main player. My service is working fine. When I do a search I my video list is updating and rendering. The issue I am having is passing the selected video to the main player. Any clues. Thanks guys

As usual any tips/sugesttions to make this just a bit easier to figure out will be apprciated.

**This is my Youtube Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-player',
  templateUrl: './video-player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-player.component.css']
})
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() thumbnail!: any;
  @Input() title!: any;
  @Output() newVideos: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  hi:string = "Video Name"
  title2:any = "Description"
  videos: VideoObject[];
  constructor(private youtubeservice: YouTubeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("YOUTUBE PLAYER COMPONENT", this.title)
    
  }
```

**Youtube Main player**

```
 <youtube-player 
    videoId="k5E2AVpwsko" 
    id="size" 
 >

</youtube-player>
        {{ hi }}
        <h5>{{ title}}</h5>
        {{ title2}}
    </div>
```

**My video List Component.... I would like to pass the selected video to the pain player**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-video-list',
  templateUrl: './video-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./video-list.component.css']
})
export class VideoListComponent implements OnInit {
videos!:VideoObject[];

constructor(private youtubeservice: YouTubeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  
    this.youtubeservice.getVids("Sesame Street").subscribe((results:any) =>{
     this.videos = results;
      console.log("List Component ", this.videos)
     });

     
  }
  updateVids(vid:VideoObject){
    this.youtubeservice.updateVids(vid).subscribe((results:any) => {
      this.videos = results;
      console.log("FROM VIDEO LIST", this.videos)
    })
  }
  
}
```

**Video List Template**

```
<app-search (searchVideos)="updateVids($event)"> </app-search>
<div>
  <app-video-list-entry
    *ngFor="let vid of videos"
    [thumbnail]="vid.snippet.thumbnails.default.url"
    [title]="vid.snippet.title"
    [channelId]="vid.snippet.channelId"
    [channelUrl]="vid.id.videoId"
  >
  </app-video-list-entry>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `VideoListEntry` component's click handler can get the `channelUrl` passed to it by the parent component. Save the `channelUrl` in component state and if the `<youtube-player>` component is located in the same component, simply pass the Url to the `<youtube-player>`